# Texture Painting leaves behind weird unpainted spots (Blender Internal)

Tags: texture-painting

I've been wanting to get into Texture painting for a while, but i've been having this problem: https://gyazo.com/23a1bfc681ba7e9583baa88159027cf8 (gif)
it happens way more and worse than this as well, it just leaves these weird unpainted spots behind. I have no idea how to fix this and i've seen so many people making texture paintings that look flawless while mines out here looking like this (when its rendered it looks even worse)

Another example: [image]

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You probably need to look at the settings for occlusion and angle so that you can do the projection - it is likely the angle is causing your projection to cut off there.

Comment: Nope, i would try every angle and no difference sadly. But i cranked up the "bleed" and it worked! Thank you for your help still!